# Remove all columns that length(unique) ==1 in R

Tags: r

Could you help me, pls. I have a data.frame :

```
  tes1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9
1    1     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     0
2    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
3    0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
4    0     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0
5    0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     0
```

I want to del test6 and test 9 ( length(unique) ==1) 
and keep all colnames remains.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# Select columns meeting the condition
colSel <- sapply( dat, function(x) length(unique(x))==1 )
# Use that logical vector to drop those columns
dat[ , !colSel ]
```

You can do it in one line by reversing the expression and using it in-line rather than saving it to a selector variable:

```
dat[ , sapply( dat, function(x) length(unique(x))>1 ) ]
```

`sapply` works here because data.frames are just lists, with each element being a column.

Comment: This is better than my answer, as it does not coerce to a matrix.

Comment: It might be simpler to reverse the original test, and save needing to use `!` - `dat[,sapply(dat,function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1)]`

Comment: For sure.  My excuse?  2am.

Comment: My personal preference would be to move the `> 1` outside of `sapply`. But it was 2 AM, so I forgive you. :-)

Comment: I think we could probably do better with `vapply` as well.  Maybe make it faster by writing the key parts in arceepeepee, etc. :-)  But I agree that there's a certain amount of conceptual integrity in saying that the sapply counts the number of unique elements per column and then you apply the logical operation to those counts.  Being ornery, I'm going to make you exercise your powers to edit (does 51K rep buy you those yet?) if it bugs you!

Answer (score 1):

Calling your data frame `d`, here is an expression which does this:

```
d[,apply(d, 2, FUN= function(x) length(unique(x))) != 1]
  tes1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test7 test8
1    1     0     1     1     1     0     1
2    0     0     0     0     0     0     1
3    0     0     1     0     1     0     0
4    0     0     1     0     0     1     1
5    0     1     1     1     1     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X = cbind( x=1, y=rnorm(10), w=rnorm(10), z =2)
keep = apply(X,2,function(x) length(unique(x))!=1)
Y = X[,keep]
```

Comment: Your `class(X)` is matrix, whereas the original post states the data is a `data.frame`.  There's a difference.

Comment: true, but it still works if one does `X = as.data.frame(cbind( x=1, y=rnorm(10), w=rnorm(10), z =2))`